# Python requests module - POST failing - invalid character 'o'

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, curl, jboss

I am trying to convert a raw curl command to use Python Request Module with no luck. This is a simple request to query JBoss Mgmt interface but it does not parse my JSON correctly.

```
16:34:26,868 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.domain.http.api] (HttpManagementService-threads - 15) Unable to construct ModelNode 'Invalid character: o'
```

Python version

```
Python 2.7.6
```

Working raw cURL command:

```
/usr/bin/curl --digest -v -L -D - 'http://brenn:!12rori@localhost:9990/management' --header Content-Type:application/json '-d {"operation":"read-attribute","name":"server-state","json.pretty":1}'
```

In python code i read in my REST/cURL payload like so

```
import requests
----
def readconfigfile():
    with open('jboss_modification.cfg') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return lines
```

The config file looks like so

```
{"operation":"read-attribute","name":"server-state","json.pretty":1}
```

I convert the str format from readconfigfile() to a dictionary as follows

```
def converttodictionary(incominglines):
commands = []
for lin in incominglines:
    #dumps = json.dumps(lin)
    obj = json.loads(lin)
    commands.append(obj)
return commands
```

The python code to execute this request is as follows

```
def applyconfig(lines):
    url="http://localhost:9990/management"
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('brenn', '!12rori')
    s = requests.Session()
    re=s.get(url,  auth=HTTPDigestAuth('brenn', '!12rori')) ##200 RESP
    s.headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    for line in lines:
        payload=line
        r=s.post(url,payload)
        print(r.text)
```

Any help much appreciated?

Note: This question has been updated a few times as I resolved other issues....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues was...

Initial JSON requestfailed  because when i read it from file python interpreted as a str.

Converted to dictionary using json.loads and server accepted request but could not parse the JSON with illegal character error

Converted this json back to a str using json.dumps -- which to my mind looks like what i was trying to do in the first place -- and this now works

1. read JSON file as per `def readconfigfile():` above
2. convert to json/dictionary as per `def converttodictionary` above: `json.loads(lin)`
3. Convert this json "back" to a string using `json.dumps` and POST as follows

   ```
   payload = json.dumps(command)

   r = session.post(url, payload,auth=HTTPDigestAuth('brenn', '!12rori')
   ```

)